# How to perform addition for each mapping iteration

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array of objects. One of the objects contains an array of objects which holds prices of each item. I want to add them up while mapping. But I am not sure how to do this?

So far I tried to map it this way, but this only renders all the cargoValues per map ( 6092
16485
6879
19980
9516) .. I thought to make a state variable and hold the values in there, however I am guessing that it will return the same value for all of the elements. Which doesn't help me..

```
          <div>
            {booking?.pallets.map((pallet: any, i: number) => (
              <div key={i}>
                {pallet?.cargoValue}
              </div>
            ))}
          </div>
```

Per each iteration ( for example main index 0 ) I would like to add each 'cargoValue' which are: 6092
16485
6879
19980
9516 and then display it as a single value (result of addition). But I'm not sure how to do it this way ?

Anyways, here's an example of such object/array.

```
0:
pallets: Array(5)
0: {cargoType: 'Engines & spare parts', stackable: false, cargoValue: '6092', count: '2', dangerous: false, …}
1: {cargoType: 'Furniture and accessories/Ceramics', stackable: false, cargoValue: '16485', count: '2', dangerous: false, …}
2: {cargoType: 'Engines & spare parts', stackable: false, cargoValue: '6879', count: '2', dangerous: false, …}
3: {cargoType: 'New Vehicles', stackable: false, cargoValue: '19980', count: '4', dangerous: false, …}
4: {cargoType: 'Industrial products', stackable: false, cargoValue: '9516', count: '2', dangerous: false, …}
length: 5
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)

1:
pallets: Array(4)
0: {cargoType: 'Chemicals & healthcare', stackable: false, cargoValue: '5741', count: '3', dangerous: false, …}
1: {cargoType: 'Old Vehicles', stackable: false, cargoValue: '18877', count: '2', dangerous: false, …}
2: {cargoType: 'Paperboard & prints', stackable: false, cargoValue: '6841', count: '1', dangerous: false, …}
3: {cargoType: 'Chemicals & healthcare', stackable: false, cargoValue: '7558', count: '1', dangerous: false, …}
length: 4
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
```

Comment: What should be expected value in this case?

Comment: @AquibAfzal for index 0 it should be 6092 + 16485 + 6879 + 19980 + 9516 = 58952... or in other words it should be the result of pallelts[0].cargoValue + pallets[1].cargoValue + pallets[2] cargoValue + pallets[3].cargoValue + pallets[4].cargoValue

Comment: Do not vandalize your own posts in an attempt to delete them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.reduce((accumulator, item) -> newAccumulator, initialValue)` to calculate the sum of your items.

For your `pallets` you could get it like this

```
const sum = pallets.reduce((acc, pallet) => acc + (+pallet.cargoValue), 0)
```

Because your `cargoValue` is a `string`, you have to convert it to a `number` with `+pallet.cargoValue` before you add it to the accumulator `acc`, otherwise it will perform a string concatenation instead of a number addition.

```
<div>
    {booking?.pallets.reduce((acc, pallet) => acc + (+pallet.cargoValue), 0)}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<div>{booking?.pallets.reduce((val:number,       pallet: any) => (
         val + pallet.cargoValue
        )),0}
</div>
```